# Exact coordinates of image using Google Street View Static API

Tags: coordinates, google-street-view, google-street-view-static-api

I'm using **Google Street View Static API** to get a streetview image of a certain object located at a certain location.
My process follows those steps:

1. First I query metadatas using my object coordinates (lat,lon). For that i'm using: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?parameters"
2. Then I get coordinates of a supposed streetview panorama (lat_pano, lon_pano )
3. Using those coordinates I query an image with heading, fov, pitch size parameters and the panorama location using "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?"

**My problem is the following**,
I define the coordinates of my image using (lat_pano, lon_pano) which are, from what I have understood, the coordinates of the vehicle. But, when I check the coordinates on the satellite image and in the streetview panorama, we are not exactly at the same place (2-3 meters of shift approximately). Also, when I try to build a url with (lat_pano, lon_pano) and open a browser using this url, once the page is fully loaded, the url changes and the coordinates also, and those coordinates seem to be better located than (lat_pano, lon_pano).

**Here's an example**:

My coordinates : (46.563276, 3.316909)
Coordinates from the metadatas request (panorama location) : (46.56322122509246, 3.316919860185686) = (lat_pano, lon_pano)

URL with those coordinates : https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=pano&viewpoint=46.56322122509246,3.316919860185686

URL once the page is loaded :
https://www.google.com/maps/@46.5631994,3.3169488,3a,75y,90t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s6TlniPdxCV98aICBlE0l0g!2e0!7i16384!8i8192?entry=ttu

Let's call (46.5631994,3.3169488) (lat_url,lon_url)

You can see the difference in the following aerial image:

[aerial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMS0O.png)

Red point is (lat_pano, lon_pano) and blue point is (lat_url, lon_url).

Code sample :

'''
import requests
from PIL import Image
import io

```
API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY"
META_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview/metadata?"
IMAGE_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?"

lat = 46.563276
lon = 3.316909

params_metadatas = {
        "key": API_KEY,
        "location": f"{lat},{lon}",
        }
        
response_metadata = requests.get(META_BASE, params=params_metadatas).json()

lat_pano,lon_pano = response_metadata["location"]["lat"], response_metadata["location"]["lng"]

sv = "https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=pano&viewpoint={},{}"

print("StreetView URL : ", sv.format(lat_pano,lon_pano))

params_img = {
        "key": API_KEY,
        "location": f"{lat_pano},{lon_pano}",
        "fov": 30,
        "heading": -7.787179920313434,
        "pitch": 0,
        "size": "640x640",
}

response_img = requests.get(IMAGE_BASE, params=params_img)

if not response_img.ok:
    raise ValueError(f"Error when getting image: {response_img}")

img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response_img.content))

img.save("test.png")

print("DONE")
```

'''

**What i've tried**

I tried to analyse the image query answer to check if there is any location informations but I haven't found anything, I also tried to collect those coordinates from the url once the page is loaded, but I always have the url that I sent and not the one once the page is loaded.

I would like to have an automatic process to gather image and correct coordinates metadatas from my input coordinates

**Help**

Did someone already face this issue? Is there any way to collect the "real" coordinates of the vehicle?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide test cases using the Street View Static API?

Comment: Hello thanks for your comment, i have added in the example section the exact code that i'm using you can also check the linked image to have an idea of my problem